# JQuery : Tooltip x-axis label for bar chart JQPlot

Tags: jquery, jqplot

I need to add a tooltip label in the each bar of the bar chart indicating what is name in x-axis. I try using highlighter but what is showing is the index numbers. Can anyone help me on how to do that?

Thanks in advance. ^_^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you adjusted the [tooltipAxes](http://www.jqplot.com/docs/files/plugins/jqplot-highlighter-js.html#%24.jqplot.Highlighter.tooltipAxes) option?

Comment: Yes, but it only shows the numbers instead of the string label

Comment: You need to provide some sample code, it works in the example I just put together here: http://jsfiddle.net/larsenmtl/jAHYc/4/

Comment: Mark, thanks, but I could not see the result of your code in that link.

Comment: Yes, Sorry, jqPlot does not allow hotlinking.  You'll need to cache the js resources in your browser before it'll work.